# ShinyIncubator: Linear regression with matrixinput

Tags: r, shiny, regression

I am sorry in advance for being new to R. I tried handling the problem on my own for a while now and can't figure it out, but I am sure it is quite easy to solve.

I want to do some statistical analysis (e.g. linear regression) and let the user input the data by himself through matrixInput.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyIncubat)

df <- data.frame(matrix(c("0","0"), 1, 2))
colnames(df) <- c("x", "y")

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Enter data (x,y) here'),
  sidebarPanel(
    matrixInput('foo', 'Foo', data=df)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "linreg")
  )
))

    server <- function(input,output) {

  lm1 <- reactive({lm(y~x,data=input$foo)})
  output$linreg <- renderPrint({summary(lm1())})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I get an error: 'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array

Comment: You could try `lm1 <- reactive({lm(y~x, data=as.data.frame(input$foo))})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stéphane Laurent said, you need to transform the userInput to a data frame. Apparently, matrixInput renames your colnames, so you also need to rename the columns of the the new data frame afterwards, otherwise your regression will fail.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyIncubator)

df <- data.frame(matrix(c("0","0"), 1, 2))
colnames(df) <- c("x", "y") # you don't need this

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Enter data (x,y) here'),
  sidebarPanel(
    matrixInput('foo', 'Foo', data=df)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "linreg")
  )
)

    server <- function(input,output) {

  lm1 <- reactive({

  lmdata<-as.data.frame(input$foo)
  names(lmdata)[1]<-'y'
  names(lmdata)[2]<-'x'

  reg<-summary(lm(y~x,data=lmdata))
  reg
  })

  output$linreg <- renderPrint({lm1()})
  # output$linreg <- renderPrint({print(input$foo)}) this way you can check how the userInput looks like

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help a newbie!

P.S. there is a ' ) ' missing in your code:
     `# output$linreg <- renderPrint({print(input$foo)})`

Just in case anyone ever tries to copy it.

Comment: Is there a way to combine `names(lmdata)` and `input$foo`? I want to build something like `inputData <- reactive({as.data.frame(input$foo(names(input$foo)[1]<-'y',names(input$foo)[2]<-'x'))})` but as you might see do I not know the correct syntax and I don't find any documentation, where I could figure out how it is done.

Comment: Do you mean something like  `inputData<-data.frame(y=input$foo[,1],x=input$foo[,2])`?

Comment: I did exactly mean that! Thank you so much.